# How to use same theme in different languages?

Tags: multisite

I have a network of wordpress sites

For example

rara.org    (English)
rara.org/fr (French)

Now I want to use the same theme which is lets say "Mytheme" for both
but I also want the in the french site words like "Search" is in french, the dates that
are shown are in french and so on.

How can I achieve this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a different language for each site in `wp-admin/options-general.php`. WordPress will load the matching language file for theme if it exists.

Be aware, you must have [these languages installed](http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/) to get the setting.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply, So how do I install these languages?
I need only french language here I guess.

Comment: @frederim I have added a link to the language repository.

Comment: Yeah thanks so how do I install these, download and put where?

Comment: @frederim Usually in `wp-content/languages`. If the directory doesn’t exist, you have to create it.

Comment: Thanks toscho, I downloaded the french Wordpress and then copied the language folder from it to my `wp-content/` and now I can change the language via `wp-admin/options-general.php` page.